# Selective 404 error on CodeIgniter installation

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I copied a fully functional CodeIgniter app into a new server, updated the `config.php` base url, and setup all database parameters accordingly.

An interesting problem I'm having is that the new install (in new server) returns a 404 for all controllers I try to access. However, when navigating to the base URL, my default controller `welcome.php` defined in `routes.php` is rendered fine on the browser.

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
```

This suggests to me that CI is running OK but there may be some other routing issue I'm not figuring out.

My `.htaccess` is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

which works fine on the other server.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: it may be due to  'case-sensitive' name of controller file. try using both capital and small letters even `$route['default_controller'] = " welcome";` even space can also cause problem

Comment: that makes sense but keep in mind this install is a clone from a fully functional one, I'm not changing CI version or anything, so it should work without changes in controller names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your apache directory configuration set to AllowOverride All?

Comment: sweet thanks, fixed it -- more info for those who may have a similar problem http://support.severalnines.com/entries/23154162-Enable-AllowOverride-for-Apache